# String (eg. "C"), I got from PreferenceManager, does not equals to "C"

Tags: android

I am facing weird situation here.

Following routine is called after I close my preference activity.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String tmp = preferences.getString("unit", "C");
CommonTool.temperatureUnit = tmp;
```

What it does is, getting the settings that I made from the preference activity and I am storing it to a global variable called CommonTool.temperatureUnit. In this case, value "C" is assigned to it.

Fine by now.

In side the CommonTool class, I have a function which returns a temperature in Celsius or Fahrenheit depends on the user preference, I got from the preference activity.

```
public static String getCommonTemperature(int celsius) {
    int ret;

    if (temperatureUnit == "C") {
        ret = celsius;
    }
    else {
        ret = (9/5) * celsius + 32;
    }

    return Integer.toString(ret);
}
```

The thing is.. it keeps fall into `else` part of it while temperatureUnit contains "C".

[Capture while in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xipIR.png)

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you ever set that preference to F for example? How? Where? Show also that code

Comment: use  if (temperatureUnit.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){....}

Comment: The `==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal or not. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) for better understanding.

Comment: I am very surprised that "==" does not compare the value. Thanks all. This issue is duplicate of "How do I compare strings in Java" as Mike said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

public static String getCommonTemperature(int celsius) {
    int ret;

```
if (temperatureUnit.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
    ret = celsius;
}
else {
    ret = (9/5) * celsius + 32;
}

return Integer.toString(ret);
```

}

Comment: Thanks Silam, ```eqaulsIgnoreCase``` or ```equals``` works perfect for my case.